# Get table names using SELECT statement in MySQL

Tags: mysql

In MySQL, I know I can list the tables in a database with:

```
SHOW TABLES
```

However, I want to insert these table names into another table, for instance:

```
INSERT INTO metadata(table_name) SHOW TABLES /* does not work */
```

Is there a way to get the table names using a standard SELECT statement, something like:

```
INSERT INTO metadata(table_name) SELECT name FROM table_names /* what should table_names be? */
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/64894/select-data-from-show-tables-mysql-query

Answer (score 549, accepted):

To get the name of all tables use:

```
SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables;
```

To get the name of the tables from a specific database use:

```
SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = 'your_database_name';
```

Now, to answer the original question, use this query:

```
INSERT INTO table_name
    SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables
        WHERE table_schema = 'your_database_name';
```

For more details see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html

Answer (score 153):

Try:

```
select * from information_schema.tables
```

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html

Comment: This points in the right direction, but does not really answers the question. Could elaborate more.

Comment: @MuriloGarcia information_schema is part of the SQL standard. Postgres has it as well. For SQLite, you look in `sqlite_master`

Comment: Fetching tables by name using LIKE:

SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.tables WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%keyword%';

Answer (score 21):

if we have multiple databases and we need to select all tables for a particular database we can use `TABLE_SCHEMA` to define database name as:

`select table_name from information_schema.tables where TABLE_SCHEMA='dbname';`

Answer (score 11):

Besides using the INFORMATION_SCHEMA table, to use SHOW TABLES to insert into a table you would use the following

```
<?php
 $sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM $dbname";
 $result = mysql_query($sql);
 $arrayCount = 0
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
  $tableNames[$arrayCount] = $row[0];
  $arrayCount++; //only do this to make sure it starts at index 0
 }
 foreach ($tableNames as &$name {
  $query = "INSERT INTO metadata (table_name) VALUES ('".$name."')";
  mysql_query($query);
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 11):

For fetching the name of all tables:

```
SELECT table_name 
FROM information_schema.tables;
```

If you need to fetch it for a specific database:

```
SELECT table_name 
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = 'your_db_name';
```

**Output:**

```
+--------------------+
| table_name         |
+--------------------+
| myapp              |
| demodb             |
| cliquein           |
+--------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 9):

```
SELECT table_name 
FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE table_schema = 'DATABASE'
```

Comment: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Answer (score 8):

Take a look at the table `TABLES` in the database `information_schema`. It contains information about the tables in your other databases. But if you're on shared hosting, you probably don't have access to it.

Answer (score 7):

MySQL `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` table contains data about both tables (not temporary but permanent ones) and views. The column `TABLE_TYPE` defines whether this is record for table or view (for tables `TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE'` and for views `TABLE_TYPE='VIEW'`). So if you want to see from your schema (database) tables only there's the following query :

```
SELECT *
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_type='BASE TABLE'
AND table_schema='myschema'
```

Answer (score 6):

I think you can get the data you want from INFORMATION_SCHEMA TABLES.

You can find more info here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/tables-table.html

Answer (score 5):

There is yet another simpler way to get table names

```
SHOW TABLES FROM <database_name>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: Helped me when I search for something that hit the title of the question.

Comment: No. This is not good as it is only shows the tables in mysql tools.

Answer (score 5):

I think it may be helpful to point out that if you want to select tables that contain specific words you can easily do it using the `SELECT` (instead of `SHOW`). Below query easily narrows down the search to tables that contain "keyword"

```
SELECT *
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_name like "%keyword%"
```

Answer (score 1):

This below query worked for me. This can able to show the databases,tables,column names,data types and columns count.

```
**select table_schema Schema_Name ,table_name TableName,column_name ColumnName,ordinal_position "Position",column_type DataType,COUNT(1) ColumnCount
FROM information_schema.columns
GROUP by table_schema,table_name,column_name,ordinal_position, column_type;**
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using information_schema.TABLES.
This works even on a cloud solution like [Skyvia](https://skyvia.com/query/online-mysql-query-builder) shown below:

[image]

With this you can simply use a SELECT statement like the above to add it up for your INSERT statement. But change the table_schema value to match the database name for your actual setup.

Answer (score 0):

To insert table names into another table using a SELECT statement in MySQL, you can query the **`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`** like this:

`INSERT INTO metadata(table_name) SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your_database_name';`

Replace `your_database_name` with the name of your database.

This approach selects all table names from the specified database and inserts them into the `metadata` table.

Answer (score -3):

To insert, update and delete do the following:

```
$teste = array('LOW_PRIORITY', 'DELAYED', 'HIGH_PRIORITY', 'IGNORE', 'INTO', 'INSERT', 'UPDATE', 'DELETE', 'QUICK', 'FROM');
$teste1 = array("\t", "\n", "\r", "\0", "\x0B");
$strsql = trim(str_ireplace($teste1, ' ', str_ireplace($teste, '', $strsql)));
$nomeTabela = substr($strsql, 0, strpos($strsql, ' '));

print($nomeTabela);
exit;
```

Comment: We expect English here. We do however have a site in Portuguese at: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/