# mysql unknown colunm in "field list" wehn selecting from derived table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an sql which select value from a table calculated by another sql:

```
select t.netlist_id from 
(select c from cl2 where pid = 1 order by id limit 1) as t
```

and I get error message below:

> #1054 Unknown column "t.netlist_id" in "field list"

if I change the original sql like this:

```
select t.* from 
(select c from cl2 where pid = 1 order by id limit 1) as t
```

I get the result of `select c from cl2 where pid = 1 order by id limit 1`

Why would this happen and how can I correct my sql?

content of table cl2

```
|pic|c       |
 ------------
|1  |dcdc    |
```

content of table dcdc

```
|netlist_id|
------------
|1         |
```

Comment: You have to select netlist_id too in the derived table!

Comment: In which table your netlist_id is? Is it in cl2?

Comment: netlist_id  is in the derived table t, it is not in cl2 @Dipen_a

Comment: But the only base table involved is cl2. From where comes netlist_id?

Comment: @Alaya : in your alias t table you have only one column c there is no other column apart from this.

Comment: If `dcdc` table is output so `t.netlist_id` should become `t.c as netlist_id`. !!! So Is'nt it?

Comment: c is the only column in the derived table

Comment: If it's unclear what is asked in the question: the a look at the link in my answer. The subquery returns a string he wants to use as a table name in another query. The subquery returns 'dcdc' and he wants to see `SELECT * FROM dcdc`. Could be achieved by a programming language but flawed design.

Comment: With thanks to @Simo Kivistö I wrote as answer but in `SQL Server`, just to show a trick, and I hope this will make a correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `SQL Server` I could suggest this answer.
But I wrote this answer, and hope make some answers in `mysql`.

In `SQL Server` there is a stored procedure named

```
Declare @text varchar(100)

Select @text = 'select * from' + (select top 1 c from cl2 where pid = 1 order by id)

Exec sp_sqlexec @text
```

This code is very useful as a stored procedure -*In SQL Server*-.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot fetch a table name from a subquery to the `FROM` clause of another query. I suggest that you merge all the tables that can appear in the column `c` of the table `cl2` and put them into one table. Put the former table name in a column like this:

table merged_tbl:

```
|netlist_id|type|
-----------------
|1         |dcdc|
```

After this you can simply do:

```
select t.netlist_id from merged_tbl AS t WHERE type IN
(select c from cl2 where pid = 1 order by id limit 1)
```

There might be another redesign moves you would have to do to your database but those cannot be known just be looking at the example data. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8334493/1288184) with a similar problem and similar suggestions.

Comment: Kivisto: Alaya is saying that cl2 is not having the netlist_id column... So this can not be the answer. He is missing something.

Comment: I want to `select netlist_id from t`, and t is the result of `select c from cl2 where pid = 1 limit 1`

Comment: @Alaya: can you please provide table structure and results for your `select c from cl2 where pid = 1 limit 1' query`

Comment: @Alaya: As I stated in my answer the only result from your subquery is column c. In case you want to use that under the name netlist_id you can simply rename the column (added that to my answer). If it's something else than renaming the subquery has to be modified...

Comment: @SimoKivistö I have edited the question and add the content of the two table.

Comment: Ok, now I get it. Short answer: this cannot be done in normal SQL. What you need to do is: explain what is stored in your tables and we will help you to redesign the database so that you don't have to fetch table names from another tables. Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8334493/1288184)

Comment: Added this info to the answer as well.