# List sql tables in pandas.read_sql

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pandas

I would like to open an SQL 2005 database (file has extension of .mdf), and I have been trying this as such:

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc

server = 'server_name'
db = 'database_name'

conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=' + server + ';DATABASE=' + db + ';Trusted_Connection=yes')

sql = """

SELECT * FROM table_name

"""
df = pd.read_sql(sql, conn)
```

Is there a way to query the database and list all tables using Pandas or pyodbc?  I have virtually NO experience in databases, so any help will be great.

Answer (score 3):

This answer might be helpful: [How do I get list of all tables in a database using TSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175415/how-do-i-get-list-of-all-tables-in-a-database-using-tsql)

Trying changing your SQL string to:

```
sql = """
SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables
"""
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import pyodbc as db

import pandas as pd

conn = db.connect("DRIVER={SQL Server}; SERVER=YourServerName; PORT=1433; DATABASE=YourDB; UID=User; PWD=Password;")

cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute('''select * from sys.databases''')

df=pd.DataFrame(cursor.fetchall())
```

Comment: you should edit this to provide context on what you did as well as format the code.

Answer (score 1):

With sqllite3 and pandas  you can do it by

```
import sqlite3 
import pandas as pd 
  
# create a connection 
con = sqlite3.connect('database.db') 
data = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT name from sqlite_master where type= "table";', con) 
  
# show first 5 table names
data.head()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `'SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables'` is that it returns a lot of information, like: 'TABLE_CATALOG', 'TABLE_SCHEMA', 'TABLE_NAME', 'TABLE_TYPE', 'ENGINE', etc.

If you need just list of table names, you can use idea from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8334493/get-table-names-using-select-statement-in-mysql):

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd

engine_new = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://YOUR_USER_NAME:YOUR_PASSWORD@DB_HOST:3306/DB_NAME")

connected_engine = engine_new.connect()

db_columns = pd.read_sql('SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = "YOUR_DB_NAME"', connected_engine)

connected_engine.close()
```

This will return a DataFrames object with 1 column 'TABLE_NAME', which you can convert to a list with:

```
list_of_database_columns = db_columns["TABLE_NAME"].to_list()
```