# Writing to SQL Server from Python

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

This is the smallest example I can give that is a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

I am attempting to do the following:

- Using `pyodbc`, read from a SQL Server instance (complete)
- Then, print that data to verify it (complete)
- Then, take that data, and insert it into a new table (or overwrite the table if it exists) <- **FAILURE**

The code is below:

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy as sa

sqlConn = pyodbc.connect(
    "DRIVER={SQL Server};"
    "SERVER=servername;"
    "DATABASE=dbname;"
    "Trusted_Connection=yes;"
)

sql = """
SELECT TOP (1000) [PART]
      ,[STEP]
      ,[COMPLETIONTIME]
  FROM [dbname].[dbo].[STEPS]
"""

engine = sa.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://servername/dbname')


df = pd.read_sql(sql, sqlConn)

df.to_sql(name = 'Test', con = engine, if_exists = 'replace', index = False)
sqlConn.commit()
sqlConn.close()
```

I get the following for an error:

```
  File "WiP.py", line 26, in <module>
    df.to_sql(name = 'Test', con = engine, if_exists = 'replace', index = False)
  File "C:\Python367-64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2712, in to_sql
    method=method,
  File "C:\Python367-64\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 518, in to_sql
    method=method,
  File "C:\Python367-64\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1319, in to_sql
    table.create()
  File "C:\Python367-64\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 641, in create
    if self.exists():
  File "C:\Python367-64\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 628, in exists
    return self.pd_sql.has_table(self.name, self.schema)
  File "C:\Python367-64\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1344, in has_table
    self.connectable.dialect.has_table, name, schema or self.meta.schema
  File "C:\Python367-64\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2162, in run_callable
    with self._contextual_connect() as conn:
  File "C:\Python367-64\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2242, in _contextual_connect
    self._wrap_pool_connect(self.pool.connect, None),
  File "C:\Python367-64\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2280, in _wrap_pool_connect
    e, dialect, self
  File "C:\Python367-64\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1547, in _handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection
    util.raise_from_cause(sqlalchemy_exception, exc_info)
  File "C:\Python367-64\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 398, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
  File "C:\Python367-64\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 152, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Python367-64\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2276, in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()
  File "C:\Python367-64\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 363, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "C:\Python367-64\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 760, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "C:\Python367-64\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 492, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "C:\Python367-64\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\impl.py", line 139, in _do_get
    self._dec_overflow()
  File "C:\Python367-64\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 68, in __exit__
    compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
  File "C:\Python367-64\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 153, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Python367-64\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\impl.py", line 136, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "C:\Python367-64\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 308, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "C:\Python367-64\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 437, in __init__
    self.__connect(first_connect_check=True)
  File "C:\Python367-64\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 639, in __connect
    connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "C:\Python367-64\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\strategies.py", line 114, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "C:\Python367-64\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 482, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (pyodbc.InterfaceError) ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/rvf5)
```

I looked that up [on this site](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/errors.html#error-rvf5), and got the following:

> Exception raised for errors that are related to the database’s
>   operation and not necessarily under the control of the programmer,
>   e.g. an unexpected disconnect occurs, the data source name is not
>   found, a transaction could not be processed, a memory allocation error
>   occurred during processing, etc.

I have also consulted:

- [Connecting to Microsoft SQL server using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33725862/connecting-to-microsoft-sql-server-using-python)
- [List sql tables in pandas.read_sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33020371/list-sql-tables-in-pandas-read-sql)
- https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql_table.html
- https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/300
- [Connecting to SQL Server 2012 using sqlalchemy and pyodbc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15750711/connecting-to-sql-server-2012-using-sqlalchemy-and-pyodbc)

I also tried switching `df.to_sql(name = 'Test', con = engine, if_exists = 'replace', index = False)` to `df.to_sql(name = 'Test', con = sqlConn, if_exists = 'replace', index = False)` but got the exact same error.

What am I doing incorrectly? How can I wrote to a new table (or overwrite an existing one) from a Pandas dataframe?

**UPDATE**

It appears the connection is failing. The following:

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

sqlConn = pyodbc.connect(
    "DRIVER={SQL Server};"
    "SERVER=servername;"
    "DATABASE=dbname;"
    "Trusted_Connection=yes;"
)

sql = """
SELECT TOP (1000) [ORDR_PART_NO]
      ,[OROP_ID]
      ,[COMPLETIONTIME]
  FROM [dbname].[dbo].[OpsLookup]
"""
engine = sa.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://servername/dbname')

cnxn = engine.connect()
result = cnxn.execute("SELECT TOP (1000) * FROM [dbname].[dbo].[STEPS]")
for row in result:
    print(row)
cnxn.close()
```

Yields:

```
C:\Python367-64\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\connectors\pyodbc.py:79: SAWarning: No driver name specified; this is expected by PyODBC when using DSN-less connections
  "No driver name specified; "
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python367-64\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2276, in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()
  File "C:\Python367-64\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 303, in unique_connection
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "C:\Python367-64\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 760, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "C:\Python367-64\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 492, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "C:\Python367-64\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\impl.py", line 139, in _do_get
    self._dec_overflow()
  File "C:\Python367-64\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 68, in __exit__
    compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
  File "C:\Python367-64\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 153, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Python367-64\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\impl.py", line 136, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "C:\Python367-64\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 308, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "C:\Python367-64\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 437, in __init__
    self.__connect(first_connect_check=True)
  File "C:\Python367-64\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 639, in __connect
    connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "C:\Python367-64\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\strategies.py", line 114, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "C:\Python367-64\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 482, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "WiP.py", line 21, in <module>
    cnxn = engine.connect()
  File "C:\Python367-64\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2209, in connect
    return self._connection_cls(self, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python367-64\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 103, in __init__
    else engine.raw_connection()
  File "C:\Python367-64\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2307, in raw_connection
    self.pool.unique_connection, _connection
  File "C:\Python367-64\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2280, in _wrap_pool_connect
    e, dialect, self
  File "C:\Python367-64\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1547, in _handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection
    util.raise_from_cause(sqlalchemy_exception, exc_info)
  File "C:\Python367-64\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 398, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
  File "C:\Python367-64\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 152, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Python367-64\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2276, in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()
  File "C:\Python367-64\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 303, in unique_connection
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "C:\Python367-64\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 760, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "C:\Python367-64\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 492, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "C:\Python367-64\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\impl.py", line 139, in _do_get
    self._dec_overflow()
  File "C:\Python367-64\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 68, in __exit__
    compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
  File "C:\Python367-64\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 153, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Python367-64\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\impl.py", line 136, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "C:\Python367-64\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 308, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "C:\Python367-64\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 437, in __init__
    self.__connect(first_connect_check=True)
  File "C:\Python367-64\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 639, in __connect
    connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "C:\Python367-64\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\strategies.py", line 114, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "C:\Python367-64\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 482, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (pyodbc.InterfaceError) ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/rvf5)
```

Comment: this connection is successful  ??     engine = sa.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://servername/dbname')

Comment: How can I test that?

Comment: with a execute like this - >  https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/connections.html

Comment: Updated the question @GiovaniSalazar

Comment: ok , then maybe this can help you - > https://communities.actian.com/s/article/Data-source-name-not-found-and-no-default-driver-specified

Comment: "SAWarning: No driver name specified ..." - For a "hostname" connection [you need to specify the `?driver=`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/mssql.html#hostname-connections) in the SQLAlchemy connection URI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`engine = sa.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://servername/dbname')`

needed to be changed to

`engine = sa.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://servername/dbname?trusted_connection=yes&driver=ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server')`

Per: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/mssql.html#hostname-connections