# Loop through some databases searching for a table

Tags: php, mysql

I want to loop through some databases (the count of the databases are undefined) searching for a table and than I want to make `SELECT` and `UPDATE` queries in that DB where I found that table.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8334493/get-table-names-using-select-statement-in-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a select against INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES to locate the table by name:

```
SELECT 
    `TABLE_SCHEMA`,
    `TABLE_NAME`,
    `TABLE_ROWS`
FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`TABLES`
WHERE `TABLE_NAME` like '%_assets'
```

Unless the desired table names might vary (different prefix, capitalization, etc.), use `= 'name'` instead of `like '%_assets'`

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions to your problem:

1). MySQL based using [Federated Engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/federated-storage-engine.html) (as mentioned by you). You can go through this [Blog post on Federated Engine](http://winashwin.wordpress.com/2012/08/22/mysql-federated-table/)

2). (As you are using PHP) Fetching data from one server, then either looping through the data and firing relevant queries to another server, or firing single aggregated query to another server based on the data fetched from first server.

Hope it will help you...

Comment: You could use a select against INFORMATION_SCHEMA to find which database contains the table. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/tables-table.html for more info.

Answer (score 0):

To list the various tables in a database you can query the database schema for the info you want.

```
select `table_name` as 'name' 
            from `information_schema`.`tables` 
            where `table_type`='base table' and `table_schema`=database();
```

The same approach can be used to find other items in the database such as `events`,`triggers`,`stored procedures` etc etc