# Search tables from SQL and show their data on page

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, html-table

I've been trying to find an easy way for this. A search (dropdown menu) of all tables in mysql, and show their content when I click the table I want to show on the page. Instead of showing just every table on the page I thought it can be easier? Any help would be appreciated! 
 My code so far:

```
<?php
$host    = "localhost";
$user    = "heijsdb_user";
$pass    = "maus";
$db_name = "heijsdb";

//create connection
$connection = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db_name);

//test if connection failed
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    die("connection failed: "
        . mysqli_connect_error()
        . " (" . mysqli_connect_errno()
        . ")");
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
echo "borsten HFP controle";
$result = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM borstenHFPcontrole");
$all_property = array();  //declare an array for saving property

//showing property
echo '<table class="data-table w3-table-all" border="2px">
        <tr class="data-heading">';  //initialize table tag
while ($property = mysqli_fetch_field($result)) {
    echo '<td>' . $property->name . '</td>';  //get field name for header
    array_push($all_property, $property->name);  //save those to array
}
echo '</tr>'; //end tr tag

//showing all data
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($all_property as $item) {
        echo '<td>' . $row[$item] . '</td>'; //get items using property value
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo "</table>";
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Comment: I think you mean
`array_push($all_property, $property);  //save those to array`
instead of
`array_push($all_property, $property->name);  //save those to array`
in the first while, right?

Comment: @timo it doesn't work if i do that

Comment: Oh, right! Sorry Muas. Yes, I've tested your solution and it works okay. So, what you need is to populate a dropdown menu with the table names and then when the user selects a table shows the content of that table in the page?

Comment: @timo exactly that :)

Comment: There are two ways to do this: refreshing the page when the user selects a table in the dropdown menu or making an AJAX request to the server to grab the info from the table and populate the table.

Which solution would you rather implement?

Comment: @timo rather go with the refreshing page, thinking you are referencing to a from with POST? No experience whatsoever with AJAX

Comment: That's correct a form with POST would be a perfect solution. You will need some interactions in JS to make this work on the `change` event of the dropdown menu. I'll prepare a simple solution for you with vanilla JS and you can go from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty much the idea, you can play from here and adapt it to your solution. Sorry I used my way, I prefer PHP template style when embedding in HTML. ;)

```
$host    = "localhost";
$user    = "heijsdb_user";
$pass    = "maus";
$db_name = "heijsdb";

//create connection
$connection = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db_name);

//test if connection failed
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    die("connection failed: "
        . mysqli_connect_error()
        . " (" . mysqli_connect_errno()
        . ")");
}

//check if the form was submitted
$table = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'table', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>showing table content on user action</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>

        <form id="form-menu" method="post">
            <label for="select-menu">Choose a table</label>
            <select id="select-menu" name="table">
                <option></option>
                <?php
                $result = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables where table_schema='test'"); // <-- the table_schema field here is your database name, change 'test' for yours
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) : $selected = $row['table_name'] == $table ? 'selected' : ''; ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $row['table_name'] ; ?>" <?php echo $selected; ?>><?php echo $row['table_name'] ; ?></option>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            </select>
        </form>

        <hr>

        <div>
            <?php if (empty($table)) : ?>
                <h3>Please select a table to show its content</h3>
            <?php else : ?>
                <h3>Content for the table `<?php echo $table; ?>`</h3>
                <?php
                $result = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM `{$table}`");
                $all_property = [];  //declare an array for saving property
                ?>
                <!-- showing property -->
                <table class="data-table w3-table-all" border="2px">
                    <tr class="data-heading"> <!-- initialize table tag -->
                        <?php while ($property = mysqli_fetch_field($result)) : ?>
                        <td><?php echo $property->name; ?></td> <!-- get field name for header -->
                        <?php $all_property[] = $property->name; //save those to array ?>
                        <?php endwhile; ?>
                    </tr> <!-- end tr tag -->

                    <!-- showing all data -->
                    <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) : ?>
                    <tr>
                        <?php foreach ($all_property as $item) : ?>
                            <td><?php echo $row[$item]; ?></td> <!-- get items using property value -->
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </tr>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                </table>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>

    </div>

    <script>
        document.getElementById('select-menu').addEventListener('change', function() {
            document.getElementById('form-menu').submit();
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Handy links:
- [Get table names using SELECT statement in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8334493/get-table-names-using-select-statement-in-mysql)
- [Examples of how to do query, style, dom, ajax, event etc like jQuery with plain javascript.](https://github.com/oneuijs/You-Dont-Need-jQuery)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you so so much! :)