# Is it possible to query table names in a database?

Tags: mysql

I just started working on a large project with hundreds of tables. I want to see all of the tables relating to DNS. I can't remember all of the table names that I'm working with, but I know they have "dns" in the name.

Is it possible to query the list of tables in a database and return just the names? It would be like `show tables;`, but filtering by table name.

An equivalent of `SHOW TABLES FROM <database> WHERE table_name LIKE '%dns%';`

Version Info: **MySQL Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.18, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get table names using SELECT statement in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8334493/get-table-names-using-select-statement-in-mysql)

Comment: @David is this a duplicate though? I looked at that question, and it still doesn't example how to filter tables by name - the where statement is querying by database name.

Comment: Yes, it's a duplicate.  You're asking how to query the names of tables, which that question is also asking and has been answered.  You can certainly change your `WHERE` clause any way you see fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the information_schema database;

`SELECT *
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = <database>
  AND table_name LIKE '%dns%'`

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use this command for filter your tables

```
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```

Reference:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/tables-table.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is possible.

```
show tables like 'pattern';
```

Where pattern is a string using wildcard characters "%","_"

- % matches any number of characters.
- _ matches exactly one character.

example : show tables like 'xxxxx%';

Refer:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/pattern-matching.html