# SUM values of specific column from all tables LIKE table_%

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need help to create an SQL query in order to SUM the values of specific column from all tables LIKE table_% as the tables will grow over time and this must cater for new table names based on the format below

---

**Scheme Name:** database_01

**Table Names:** tb_data_'*YEAR*'_'*MONTH*'

---

- *YEAR* and *MONTH* are both values which range from all 12 months and years from 2011 to 2018.

Each Table contains a column called TOTAL_VALUE. I have a php script that triggers an SQL query to pull data from the database.

I would like to SUM the total of each tables TOTAL_VALUE column and save the value for my script below to push the array.

```
$sql = "SELECT TOTAL_VALUES FROM tb_data_2017_october";   
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

$data = array(); while($enr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $a =  array($enr['TOTAL_VALUES']);
    foreach ($a as $as){
        echo "'".$as."', ";}
    array_push($data, $as); }
```

I have been trying to alter the SQL with options such as:

```
SELECT id FROM table1
    UNION
    SELECT id FROM table2
    UNION
    SELECT id FROM table3
    UNION
    SELECT id FROM table4
```

However i need to cater for the ability to check all tables that are like tb_data_%

Comment: This is a bad database design. If you can - rethink it.

Comment: Agreed with you, however currently this is how the data sits. Migration to single database with columns specifying the data must be done. However I would appreciate any feedback on a possible solution for current. Thanks for your response though.

Comment: Then select all tables from `schema` with names that you need and create a big union query.

Comment: what database server are you using?

Comment: hint: use a loop

Comment: There are new Tables every month, do you know of the method to have it select the table with a similar function to the WHERE LIKE 'name%'

Comment: I am using mySQL 5.1

Comment: Why such an old version?

Comment: Start with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8334493/get-table-names-using-select-statement-in-mysql

Comment: I tried Dynamic methods from previous stackoverflow questions based on my searchs but my query window states it does not know the language in my version.

Comment: You can also use a the `FEDERATED` engine to create a virtual table that's the union of all those tables. Every month you update the definition of this table to add the new table.

Comment: Oops, I meant the [MERGE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/merge-storage-engine.html) engine.

Comment: Thanks for the above comments and link. I will read into these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this question for information about getting the list of tables: [Get table names using SELECT statement in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27001800/4458445)

You can get the list of tables in one query result, and then query each table. I'll rework your code slightly to give an example:

```
// Get the tables
$tables_sql = "SELECT table_name 
                FROM information_schema.tables 
                WHERE table_schema='<your DB>' 
                AND table_name LIKE 'tb_data%'";  

$tables = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

// Iterate over the tables
while($table = mysqli_fetch_assoc($tables)){
{
    /*
    * Your code
    */

    // This query assumes that you can trust your table names not to to an SQL injection
    $sql = "SELECT TOTAL_VALUES FROM " . $table['table_name']; 
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    $data = array(); while($enr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $a =  array($enr['TOTAL_VALUES']);
        foreach ($a as $as){
            echo "'".$as."', ";
        array_push($data, $as); }
}
```

You can do whatever you need once your have your list of tables. You can build one big union query (which would be more efficient than querying each table individually), or feed the tables to the `MERGE` engine, as in [barmar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49520871/4458445)

Comment: The following code in full errors relating to sudden end to file. No Echo is resulting unfortunately, could this be based on the table not pulling through the TOTAL_VALUE column?

Comment: @user9560017 It looks like it is because the code that I copied from your question had an extra `}` in it. I've just edited the question to remove the `}` at the end of your echo line (`echo "'".$as."', ";`) in my example.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [MERGE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/merge-storage-engine.html) storage engine to create a virtual table that combines all the monthly tables.

```
CREATE TABLE tb_all_data (
    ...
) ENGINE=MERGE UNION=(tb_data_2017_october, tb_data_2017_november, ...);
```

List all the tables in the `UNION=` list, and update it whenever you create a new table.

Then you can just query from `tb_all_data`.

Comment: Thanks for this share, is there any limitations i should be cautious about as each table have around 250,000 rows. Also there is no reference in the tables of the month and year, this is only in the table name.

Comment: @user9560017 At 250k rows, you should definitely select the `sum(TOTAL_VALUES)`, and not each individual row.

Comment: @user9560017 From the documentation: The maximum number of rows in a MERGE table is 2^64 (~1.844E+19). If each table contains about 250K rows, you can only combine 72 trillion tables.

Comment: Read the documentation I linked to for more caveats.

Comment: There will probably be performance issues if you combine many tables like this, but the same thing happens if you write a `UNION` query.

Comment: You wouldn't use the merged table for queries that need to be specific to a particular month and year, then you use the month-specific table.

Comment: I am running a few other tests now based on the documentation, will let you know the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Try this- it will loop through all the tables with the pattern you want and create sums for you:

```
declare @table table (rowid int identity, name varchar(max))
        insert @table
        select name from sys.tables where name like '%yourname%'

        declare @holding table (name varchar(max), sumvalue int)

        declare @iterator int = 1
        declare @tablename varchar(max)
        while @iterator<=(select max(rowid) from @table)
        begin
        select @tablename=name from @table where rowid=@iterator

        insert @holding
        exec('select '+@tablename+' sum(TOTAL_VALUE)TOTAL_VALUE from '+@tablename+' group by +'+@tablename+'')

        set @iterator=@iterator+1
        end 

    select * from @holding
```