# Dropping a table in mySQLi db if contains value in name

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to delete one or multiple tables at once in my mySQLi db if it contains a string variable. So for example lets say I have 5 tables in my db:

Table 1 -
name: db_table1_hello

Table 2 -
name: db_table2_world

Table 3 -
name: db_table3_hello

Table 4 -
name: db_table4_world

Table 5 -
name: db_table5_hello

Now I have a variable called `tableString` and has the value `hello`, in theory it would then be used to drop table 1, 3, and 5.

Not really sure on the best way to go about doing this so I thought I'd post it and get an idea from someone with a little more experience then me.

Thanks in advance guys.

EDIT:

```
$sql = "";

    if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){

        header("Location: " . $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);

    } else {  

        echo "Table deletion unsuccessfully<br> ";  

    }
```

Comment: You can get table names by `SHOW TABLES [FROM db_name] [LIKE 'pattern']`, and than drop tables that it found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8334493/get-table-names-using-select-statement-in-mysql) SO Answer, you can filter tables names from `information_schema.tables` table like this:

```
SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name like '%hello%';
```

So you can create a statement englobing the previous select in this way:

```
DELIMITER $$
SET @s = SELECT CONCAT('DROP TABLE ',table_name,';') 
         FROM   information_schema.tables 
         WHERE table_name like '%hello%'$$
DELIMITER ;
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt1;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
```

EDIT:

The question has changed asking for a PHP routine to drop tables.
In PHP you should run the first SQL to get table names, then delete with a loop those tables:

```
$tableString = "hello";

$sql = "SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name like '%$tableString%'";

$res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
    $tname = $row[0];
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, "DROP TABLE $tname");
    if (!$result) echo "Table $tname deletion unsuccessfully<br> ";  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, I've added an edit to my post. How would I implement this into my query `$sql`?