# If Tables In Database

Tags: php, sql

I am creating a PHP application where they input their database information and my program will connect to the database and insert tables. I want to first ensure there are no current tables in the database and if there are I would like to throw them an error.

I have already tried "SELECT COUNT(*)" but when I try to run that it says:

> "Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to int".

```php
      $check = 'SELECT COUNT(*)';
      $val = $connection->query($check);

      if ($val > 0) {
        header("Location: ../../db-setup.php?notclean");
      }

      else {
        $sql = 'CREATE TABLE `test` (`name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL);';
        $connection->query($sql) or die();
        header('Location: ../../db-setup.php?success');
      }
```

I tried this configuration and even if there is no tables in the database it still throws me my notclean created error.

So I tried...

```php
      $check = 'SELECT COUNT(*)';
      $val = $connection->query($check);

      if ($val > 1) {
        header("Location: ../../db-setup.php?notclean");
      }

      else {
        $sql = 'CREATE TABLE `test` (`name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL);';
        $connection->query($sql) or die();
        header('Location: ../../db-setup.php?success');
      }
```

After trying this, if there is nothing in the database it will create the tables, as I wanted. But, if there is something in the database it throws a weird error:

> "Notice: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to
>   int".

Comment: weird ! why you don't specify a table for the `SELECT` statement ? You'll get `1` as the count (even if you don't select a database !).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Problem

First of all, let me show you why you get the error :

- the `query` method returns a `mysqli_result` object that holds the results (rows maybe) from the query.
- when you use `$val > 1`, `PHP` tries to cast the `$val` variable (which is a `mysqli_result` object) to an `integer` (that can't happen) thus you get the error.

I saw a weird query used in your code, `SELECT COUNT(*)` will **always** return `1` ! You need to specify a `FROM` clause here.

*...I want to first ensure there are no current tables in the database...* To do so, you could use a query like `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'DB_NAME'` where `DB_NAME` is the database you're using to stores/create the tables.

## Solution

So, to solve the issue you need to fetch (and assign the result to a variable) the returned `mysqli_result` object (`$val` variable) using a method like `fetch_assoc` (return an associative `array`) and then use the variable in which you stored the result in (which is an associative `array`) to get the count you need. You'll use something like :

```php
$check = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS `c` FROM `information_schema`.`tables` WHERE `table_schema` = 'DB_NAME';"; /** COUNT(*) is aliased as c to simply get it using $result['c'] later **/
$val = $connection->query($check);
$result = $val->fetch_assoc();
if($result['c'] > 0) { /** or just if($val->fetch_assoc()['c'] > 0) after the ->query call as you don't need to hold the result from the query (you don't/won't it need/use it later) **/
  header("Location: ../../db-setup.php?notclean");
} else {
  $sql = 'CREATE TABLE `test` (`name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL);';
  $connection->query($sql) or die();
  header('Location: ../../db-setup.php?success');
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

A random call to `SELECT 'foo'` with no table specified is not an error, and will return something reasonable.

The general pattern is to use `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ...` and use that unconditionally.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
  `name`  varchar(255) not null,
);
```

Most SQL dialects support this.  Since you don't list your SQL server I can't comment for sure.  I guess mysql because you mention 'mysqli_result', and [mysql does in fact support](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html) `IF NOT EXISTS`.

If you *really* want to avoid `IF NOT EXISTS`, you need to do a SQL-dialect specific query -- `DESCRIBE DATABASE` or `SHOW TABLES` or `SELECT table_names FROM all_tables` or whatever.

Comment: Thanks so much. How would I go about retrieving an error if there are other tables, so I can print that to the screen?

Comment: Depends on the database engine in question. For mysql, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8334493/get-table-names-using-select-statement-in-mysql).  Once you query the names, you can decide if you should throw an error.