# How to get the Table Name after establishment a database connection using appache airflow

Tags: python, database, airflow

I am using appache airflow for database connection .

I am using for the following code

```
>>> import json
>>> from airflow.models.connection import Connection

>>> c = Connection(
>>>     conn_id='some_conn',
>>>     conn_type='mysql',
>>>     description='connection description',
>>>     host='myhost.com',
>>>     login='myname',
>>>     password='mypassword',
>>>     extra=json.dumps(dict(this_param='some val', that_param='other val*')),
>>> )
>>> print(f"AIRFLOW_CONN_{c.conn_id.upper()}='{c.get_uri()}'")
AIRFLOW_CONN_SOME_CONN='mysql://myname:mypassword@myhost.com?this_param=some+val&that_param=other+val%2A'
```

Now the Data Establishment was done . But How do I get the tables associated with that perticulat DataBase

Answer (score 0):

You can get the tables in the database by using [`MySqlOperator`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-mysql/stable/_api/airflow/providers/mysql/operators/mysql/index.html) with a query like this:

```
SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = 'your_database_name';
```

[more on the query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27001800/6942134)

Comment: cursor.execute(f"SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables where table_schema ='{c.schema}';")

Comment: Are you mentioning like this