# How can i SELECT from all tables at once?

Tags: mysql

I have 32 tables in mySQL database and i wanna select from them where the table contains a specific value. I want to do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM * WHERE DeviceId = '2009240214';
```

I know there are many tables which contains the DeviceId. instead of join one by one, is there a way i can select all of them at once to get the result where DeviceId = '2009240214' is in the table?

Thank You

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get table names using SELECT statement in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8334493/get-table-names-using-select-statement-in-mysql)

Comment: **all** your tables have a field named `DeviceId` ?

Comment: Maybe this do
`SELECT * FROM <table1>, <table2>, <table3>,....<table32> WHERE DeviceId = '2009240214';`

Comment: @Raky this is a terrible idea to cross join 32 tables

Comment: @Cid, Sir but still it's an Idea for a beginner to begin with.

Comment: @Arthur, You can Create a Procedure.

Comment: Not all of them have DeviceId, i know i can select one by one, but i'd like to know if there's a way to select from all of the at once

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? This looks like horrible database design

Answer (score 0):

Following SQL statement will list all tables in DB named `books` with `Column_Name` `device_id`

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS books.raky;
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE PROCEDURE books.raky()
BEGIN
    DECLARE done BIGINT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE table_name CHAR(255) DEFAULT "";
    DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='books' AND COLUMN_NAME IN ('ISBN10')  ;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
    open cur1;
    
    myloop: loop
        fetch cur1 into table_name;
          
        if done then
            leave myloop;
        end if;
        set @sqlraky = CONCAT("select * from `books`.", table_name, " where ISBN10 = '0195153448'");
        SELECT @sqlraky;
        prepare stmt from @sqlraky;
        execute stmt;
        drop prepare stmt;
    end loop;
    close cur1;
END; 
;;
call books.raky;
```

Please try the above code. Replace `books` with your database name and `ISBN10` with `DeviceID`. Also, change the value in `ISBN10 ='0195153448'` with `DeviceId = '2009240214';`

This is as close as I could Get. And I know there is scope for Improvement.

Comment: @Cid, If you may please kindly improve my code