# List tables in all the databases

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three databases in `mysql`. And I would like to list all the tables in each database. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get table names using SELECT statement in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8334493/get-table-names-using-select-statement-in-mysql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select table_schema as database_name, table_name
    from information_schema.tables
where table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
    and table_schema not in ('information_schema','mysql',
                             'performance_schema','sys')
order by database_name, table_name;
```

Comment: INFORMATION_SCHEMA It is an ANSI standard set of views that is supported in many RDBMS as listed in this Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_schema