# How to select table from syntax show on mysql, without using procedure?

Tags: mysql, sql

i have read this article [Select data from “show tables” MySQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64894/select-data-from-show-tables-mysql-query) . But i need to get table from show tables. I try this syntax at the first.

> show tables from pos where `tables_in_pos` like  (select kdtk from
>   toko)

and then the value has show

> +-------------------+ 
>   | tables_in_pos |
>
> +-------------------+ 
>   |      fnpk     |

after that i try this syntax

> select * from concat(show tables from pos where `tables_in_pos` like  (select kdtk from toko),'a') as Hasil

How to select table from syntax **Show** on mysql? without using Procedure.

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/64894/select-data-from-show-tables-mysql-query

Comment: @Ravinder yes i have read it....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the query as follows,You need to include conditions in your query to get them the way you want:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='your DB_Name' AND........{additional conditions }....
```