# Can I create a view from show tables?

Tags: mysql

I have to support a poorly organized database with hundreds of tables. Setting up a view that would display the subset of tables associated with general debugging would really help. Luckily, the tables I don't want all match the same pattern. Is there any way to do something like

```
Create view DebugTables show tables where tables_in_DB not like 'pt%'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/64894/select-data-from-show-tables-mysql-query

Comment: Definitely related, and I could have used that. You have no idea how useless googling 'view show tables' is. Hopefully this will help

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you can't do this in that way. But you can try like this:

```
CREATE VIEW DebugTables AS 
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your_db_name' AND TABLE_NAME NOT LIKE 'pt%'
```